# Connection web server to browser (Python)

Tags: python, browser, webserver, python-multithreading

I tried to make a web server by using socket and threading(for multi-threading). I tried to connect this server with 127.0.0.1:8888 but it failed.
As I am a starter of python, it is hard for me to catch errors. Please help me to fix these errors. 
Here is the code.

(+I am using python 2.7, the error I got was 127.0.0.1 denied the connection from the browser, there was no error message on python.)

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import socket
import threading
import time
#making method

class Handler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        #error handling
        if self.protocol_version != 'HTTP/1.1':
            self.send_error(400)
            return
        elif  self.path !='/':
            self.send_error(404)
            return
        else:
            self.send_respose(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-length', 1024)
            self.end_headers()
    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write('Hello World')
        return
    def do_PUT(self):
        content_length=int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        put_data=self.rfile.read(content_length)
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write('Hello World')
        return

#making one socket
sock=socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('',8888))
sock.listen(5)

#multi threading
class Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, i):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.i=i
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('',8888), Handler)
        server.socket=sock
        server.server_bind=self.server_close= lambda self: None
        server.serve_forever()

if __name__=='__main__':

    print('Started WebServer on port 8888')
    [Thread(i) for i in range(100)]
    time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: Could you write the error you are getting, your operating system and if it is python 2.x or 3.x? Also there is typo here: `self.headers['Conetnt-Length'] `

Comment: Is there an application listening on port 8888? Not sure what OS you're using, but in Linux you would type something like `netstat -tulpan | grep 8888`.

Comment: @cmertayak Thank you for letting me know typo:) I edited this with answering your questions.

Comment: Is there any reason for you, not to use existing (python) web servers or frameworks ?

Comment: @mattias I am using windows. I am going to check if there is the method that is similar to Linux's. Thank you!

Comment: I agree with @MauriceMeyer . What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why not to use some standard simple python servers with ThreadingMixin?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I just wanted to make my own web server but I cannot find the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: @stella Why do you want to make hundred servers in separate threads? Why are you not letting one server handle requests in separate threads? Do you have any reason for this?

Comment: The reason is: You cant run 100 threads listening on the same port.

Comment: @kyjanond That's actually what I didn't intend to do.. I tried to make this server to handle multiple simultaneous service requests. Then how can I fix this code? Move run function into main?

Comment: @stella then refer to my answer bellow please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not fully understand why are you trying to spin 100 threads listening on the same port but I will suggest it is a mistake. Please refer to this [blog post](https://pymotw.com/2/BaseHTTPServer/index.html#threading-and-forking) about how to make very simple HTTP servers in python (including some threading example). Bellow you can find a simple threaded server that handles each request in separate thread. I hope it will help.

```
     from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
     from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
     import threading

     class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
         """This is a handler that will answer the requests"""
        def do_GET(self):
             self.send_response(200)
             self.end_headers()
             message =  "Hello stella this is thread: "+threading.currentThread().getName()
             self.wfile.write(message)
             return

     class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
         """This is the server that will use your handler."""

     if __name__ == '__main__':
         server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('', 8888), Handler)
         print "Press Ctrl-C to stop"
         try:
             server.serve_forever()
             print "Server is up"
         except KeyboardInterrupt:
             server.shutdown()
             print "Server is down"
```